# What is the meaning of "A secret makes a woman woman"?

Tags: word-usage

"A secret makes a woman woman."

This is a phrase that appears in a popular anime series "Detective Conan", a.k.a. "Case Closed" in North America.

Is this English correct?  If so, why doesn't the second "woman" have a determiner?  I guess the sentence means to say that a woman is more attractive when she has a secret.

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of the sentence is correct. It means that a secret makes a woman truly a woman. The statement itself references the mystique of womenkind, that there is always something mysterious about a woman, something just beyond the grasp of men to understand.

Grammatically, it is omitting some words. You can understand it better as "A secret makes a woman (truly/actually/etc a) woman. The "truly/actually/etc a" is an adverb phrase, describing how the secret makes a woman a woman.

Answer (score 0):

It's bad grammar, and worse than that, unclear in meaning.

For the grammar to work, the second "woman" would have to be a verb, an adjective, or a mass noun, but the word "woman" is none of those things.

Without the surrounding context, it's impossible to say what it's supposed to mean, so I can't suggest alternatives with good grammar.

An alternative is that the writer is being poetic. If this is the case, then it's beyond the rules of grammar, which makes it off-topic.

Comment: She felt a tingle in that part of her that was truly woman - isn't 'woman' an adjective there?

Comment: "I am Woman" - song by Helen Reddy, "We are Woman" (US feminist group),  [Female Trouble](https://www.newyorker.com/culture/comma-queen/female-trouble-the-debate-over-woman-as-an-adjective) - The Debate over Woman as an Adjective (The New Yorker).

Comment: I don't think that the second "woman " *has* to be a mass noun - English can be kind of flexible with considering nouns as count or mass or attributive, especially if speaking poetically or informally.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Those are both poetic uses. Poetic license allows for infinite variations. I'm treating the OP's example sentence as not poetry, otherwise it's no longer a language learning question.

Comment: I think the OP's quoted sentence is arguably "poetic" in some sense.

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Agreed. If it's poetic, it's off-topic. I've added this possibility to my answer